# Unicode values from php server 

Tags: android, android-layout, unicode, unicode-string

I am getting values from a MySQL database via php and display them inside an Android ListView. It works fine, but how do I print unicode strings? Like if I do it within Android e.g string `a="\u1EA7"`; and print it then it wil work fine but if i am getting the same code from the databases XML and saving it as string `a=XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Name")` but it is printing the exact \u1EA7 string it is not converting in the unicode.

Comment: If you would spend more time writing the question you may get a proper answer. Reformat, split it to paragraphs and remove things like "urgent help".

Answer (score 0):

JSONTokener takes care of this for the JSON parser.

I guess you can take advantage of it without actually having JSON with something like:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(myString + "'");
String decoded = tokener.next('\'');
```

or simply copy the code from http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20070829/org/json/JSONTokener.java#JSONTokener.nextString%28char%29